# How to change alarm volume without making sound?

Tags: alarm

It's night, everybody is sleeping but I realized that my phone's alarm volume is at 1. This isn't enough to wake me up, but I know that if I change it, it will make a sound and wake up everybody. Is there a app that lets me change this volume without actually playing a sound, or a completely different alarm app that doesn't do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certainly simpler solutions, but I use Tasker and it is also possible with it.

In Tasker simply create a new task there you can set the different volume (alarm, ring tone, ...). Then execute the task manually and the set volume is accepted.

Comment: Brilliant solution! I did that but used Automate because it's free. Worked perfectly.